# Express + Node: file downloaded through response.download() different size compared to original file

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working on a simple web-server using Node + Express. Let me explain the section where I'm facing a strange issue.

Using an external script (dropbearkey) I'm generating a key-pair and the generated private key is stored on the server's filesystem. The objective is to send this private key as a response to a client's request. The Client is an application developed using Electron.

In order to do so, I'm using the following:

```
response.download(filepath);
```

**filepath** in the above line is the path to the generated private key on the server's filesystem. This is a binary file.

The problem is, the file downloaded on the client's side is bigger in size in comparison to the original file. Any idea why? Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

[Original File (on Server)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rstnywvwfjhxwaq/original_file?dl=0)

[Downloaded File (on Client)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o6r3furht96jen1/downloaded_file?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original file is (incorrectly) being treated as being an UTF-8-encoded file.

I can create the downloaded file from the original like so:

```
const fs = require('fs');
process.stdout.write( fs.readFileSync('original_file').toString() );
```

Check the client to make sure that it doesn't interpret the data as a string, but as a (binary) Buffer.